# Change the position of text in double slider

Tags: python, streamlit

I defined a double slider in stream lit app, I want to write the start point text on top and the end point text on bottom, or even slightly higher than start point in case texts don't overlap if the start and end point are too close, how should I modify it?

```
slider = cols1.slider('Select date', min_value=start_dt, value=[start_dt,index_dt] ,max_value=end_dt, format=format)
```

Comment: The way you could have had it done is through inspection to change the css rule of one of the sliders but its unfortunate that they both share the same class. which means any css modification will be applied to both sliders.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a great way to do this with `st.slider`. You could use CSS to make the font size for both labels smaller to prevent them from overlapping. Have you considered using [`st.date_input`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.date_input) instead, since it looks like you're using the sliders for date input?